# Find references of a class in multiple .NET projects

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a class, say `Worker`, and I have a thousand of .NET (including Core) projects potentially using that class.

In order to refactor this class, I would like to know where and how much is used.

Is there a tool or a way to find all the references to that class, to obtain like a dependency graph for this class?

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: if there is a freeware alternative, I would prefer, we have NDepend, not the Resharper...

Answer (score 2):

ndepend is one option - https://www.ndepend.com/

You can create a dependency diagram in the visual studio itself

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/create-layer-diagrams-from-your-code?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019

Comment: great article for Visual Studio, hope this to be a multi VS-solution-project solution